# How to sort an array of objects in the same order as an id array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of players objects like this :

```
    var players = [{
        id: "thisIsID1",
        name: "William",
        otherProps
    },
    {
        id: "thisIsID2",
        name: "Shakespeare",
        otherProps
    },
    {
        id: "thisIsID3",
        name: "Lola",
        otherProps
    }]
```

And I have and array of their ID that has been shuffled, like so :

```
var shuffledIDs = ["thisIsID2", "thisIsID3", "thisIsID1"]
```

How can I sort the `players` var so the objects are in the same order as the corresponding IDs of `shuffledIDs` ?

*Edit: different names just for the sake of making players different*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is short, then you can sort it with the following one-liner:

```js
players = shuffledIDs.map(id => players.find(v => v.id == id))
```

Essentially, for every id in `shuffledID`, it finds the element in `players` with that id and puts it in the correct spot. However, this takes O(n^2) time so it might not scale well for larger data. If you want a faster method, you can maintain an object of IDs:

```js
var ids = {};
players.forEach(v => ids[v.id] = v);
players = shuffledIDs.map(v => ids[v]);
```

Comment: I think the latter is the most efficient method I've got !  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using array `.find()` method:

```js
var players = [{
        id: "thisIsID1",
        name: "William"
    },
    {
        id: "thisIsID2",
        name: "Shakespeare"
    },
    {
        id: "thisIsID3",
        name: "Lola"
    }]

var shuffledIDs = ["thisIsID2", "thisIsID3", "thisIsID1"]
var result = shuffledIDs.map(x => players.find(p=>p.id === x))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create object with keys and values as index from shuffle array.
Use `sort` method and prioritize bases above shuffled indexes. This way should even the case of duplicate data in players.

```js
var players = [
  {
    id: "thisIsID1",
    name: "William"
  },
  {
    id: "thisIsID2",
    name: "Shakespeare"
  },
  {
    id: "thisIsID3",
    name: "Lola"
  }
];

const shuffleIds = ["thisIsID2", "thisIsID3", "thisIsID1"];

const shuf_idx = Object.fromEntries(shuffleIds.map((x, i) => [x, i]));

players.sort((a, b) => shuf_idx[a.id] - shuf_idx[b.id]);

console.log(players);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) where using index of the element:

```js
const shuffledIDs = ["thisIsID2", "thisIsID3", "thisIsID1"];
const players = [{ id: "thisIsID1", name: "William" }, { id: "thisIsID2",       name: "Shakespeare" }, { id: "thisIsID3", name: "Lola" }];

const result = players.map((e, i) => players.find(f => f.id === shuffledIDs[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If there is a value in `shuffledIDs` that doesn't match a value in `players`, this approach returns an undefined element in `result` array. Is there a way to prevent this?